# Android App local database update on playstore

Tags: android, sqlite

I have published an Android App having local **Sqlite** database with **versionCode = 1 and DATABASE VERSION = 1** with two tables suppose **TABLE1** and **TABLE2**.
If I want to add one more table **TABLE3** then I will write the table creation code in **onUpgrade()** method and will publish my App
with **versionCode = 2 and DATABASE VERSION = 2** and User will get the update from play store.
What if I want to add **TABLE4** for **versionCode = 3 and DATABASE VERSION = 3**, I sholuld write the code in onUpgrade() method but Should I **remove** the table creation code 
for **TABLE3** and if not will it give a

> Table already exist error

for **TABLE3**  When user will update the app to **version = 3**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#onUpgrade(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,%20int,%20int)) method provides the old version number, so you just have to check which version was it. For example, if `oldVersion` equals to 1, you have to add TABLE3 and TABLE4 too, but if it equals to 2, you just need TABLE4. The easiest way to manage it is probably like this:

```
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    if (oldVersion < 2) {
        // create TABLE3
    }

    if (oldVersion < 3) {
        // create TABLE4
    }
}
```

TL;DR: You should not remove the TABLE3 creation part because if a user doesn't install the upgrade between version 1 and 3, he/she won't have that table added and your app will probably crash at some point.

Answer (score 0):

`onUpgrade()` should upgrade the database from any version to the current one. You should also modify `onCreate()` to create all the tables needed in the current version.